# Continuous, injective curve that is not an embedding (Descartes folium)

Tags: calculus, general-topology, differential-geometry, curves

Consider the curve $x:\left(-1,+\infty\right) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by:

$x\left(t\right)= (x_1(t),x_2(t)) = \Big(\frac{3t}{1+t^3},\frac{3t^2}{1+t^3}\Big)$

i.e. *"half"* the parametrisation of Descartes folium

Then it is continuous and injective, but is not a homeomorphism onto its image.

***Why?***

Injectivity is ok.

For the second point, the inverse function is:

$x^{-1}(t) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x_2}{x_1} & \text{ if }x_1 \in \left(-\infty,a\right]\setminus\{0\},a>0,x_2 \in \left[0,+\infty\right) \\
0 & \text{ if }x_1=0
\end{cases}$

Now, where the problem for continuity of the inverse occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}^2\supset C \to [-1,+\infty)$ where $C$ is image of $x$, and $f=x^{-1}$:
$$
f\left((x_1,x_2)\right) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       0 & : x_1=0\\
       \frac{x_2}{x_1} & : otherwise
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$
Define sequence $\{s_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ where $s_k=(\frac{3k}{1+k^3},\frac{3k^2}{1+k^3})$.
$$\{s_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}\subset C$$
$$f(0,0)=0$$
$$f(s_k)=k$$
$$\lim_{k\to +\infty}s_k=(0,0) $$
$$\lim_{k\to +\infty}f(s_k)=+\infty$$
$$\lim_{s_k\to (0,0)}f(s_k)\neq f(0,0)$$

therefore $f$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 2):

So, $x(0) = (0,0)$. Further, note that $\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t) = (0,0)$. So, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists some arbitrarily large $t_0$ (say, $t_0 > 1$) such that $\vert x(t_0)\vert < \varepsilon$. Therefore, the preimage of any $\varepsilon $-ball containing $(0,0)$is not going to be contained within a $\delta$-ball in $\mathbb{R}$ with radius less than $1$, and so the inverse is not continuous.